# Remove unwanted space on <td> table

Tags: html, css

I happened to have trouble removing the extra space between rows. I'm guessing this was caused by the multi-lined textbox Address and Remarks but not really sure why it happened to add an extra padding-top for the others.

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 490,
  width: 830,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  position: ['center', 50]
});


<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px; padding-left:130px;">
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:CheckBox ID="active" Checked="true" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">&nbsp;&nbsp;Active &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabelBold">Group Name:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="groupName" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="1"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px">
        <div style="float:left" id="contactPersonTextName" class="controlLabelBold">Contact Person:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="contactPerson" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="6"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabelBold">Group Code:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="groupCode" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="2"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabelBold">Contact Number:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="collectorContactNumber" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" MaxLength="20" tabindex="7"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px;">
        <div style="float:left" id="collectorTextName" class="controlLabelBold">Account Officer:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="collectorName" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="3"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="height:60px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabel">Total Exposure Amount:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="totalExposureAmount" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" CssClass="controlNumeric" tabindex="8"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:30px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabel">E-mail:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="collectorEmail" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="4"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="height:60px">
        <div style="float:left;" class="controlLabel">Remarks:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="remarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="9"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="height:60px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabelBold">Address:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="address" runat="server" style="display:block" SkinID="textBoxField" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" tabindex="5"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none;">
      <div style="height:30px">
        <div style="float:left" class="controlLabel">Security of Payment:</div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <asp:TextBox ID="securityOfPayment" runat="server" SkinID="textBoxField" tabindex="10"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So far i've tried setting these:

```
table: cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
td: padding: 0;
```

But nothing works. Help?

**FORM**

[image: FORM]

**CSS**

[image: CSS]

Comment: Judging by the picture there does not seem to be much padding in the resulting table. The selected `<td>`'s height is probably governed by the neighboring "Remark"-`<td>`'s height. The word "E-mail" does not have much padding on the left of it!

Comment: Could you provide more informations (more html) even if I think it's  a matter of vertical-align on <td> ?

Comment: @cars10 I've tried setting the height lower but there werent any changes.

Comment: @MerOnLand add a rule "vertical-align: top" on your <td>

Comment: @Fahrenheit edit: It worked. Big Thanks!!